# Outlook$CreateItem(0) crashes R (using package RDCOMClient)

Tags: r, outlook, rdcomclient, com-automation

I solved this issue but documenting here in case anyone experiences difficulty using RDCOMClient to send Outlook emails via R.

Using fresh install of Windows 10 Pro for Workstations running as a VirtualBox VM, R version 4.1.1, Rstudio 2021.09.0 (Build 351), and Microsoft Office365 Outlook client (version 2102 (Build 13801.20960 Click-to-Run)).

The following code causes R to crash every time on the last line:

```
install.packages("RDCOMClient", repos = "http://www.omegahat.net/R")
library(RDCOMClient)

# Open Outlook
Outlook <- COMCreate("Outlook.Application")

# Create a new message
Email = Outlook$CreateItem(0)
```

I rolled back the R version to 3.5.1 -- and it now works.

Conclusion: RDCOMClient is not compatible with latest version of R (4.1.1).

Comment: Have you tried getting the Inbox folder or using the Logon method before creating a new item on the problematic version of R?

Comment: Could you also then post the error messages / problems you experienced so that people are more likely to find this answered question? You can also ask a question and post an answer and then mark the answer as 'community wiki'.

Comment: @LexibOy -- Good idea -- I would love to post the error, but I can't find any log file associated with it. That last command when run in R causes R simply to exit without warning. In RStudio, this event is caught by RStudio and described as "R encountered a fatal error. The session was terminated"

Comment: Again, have you tried getting the `Inbox` folder or using the `Logon` method before creating a new item on the problematic version of R?

Answer (score 0):

I rolled back the `R` version to `3.5.1` -- and it now works.

Conclusion: `RDCOMClient` is not compatible with latest version of `R (4.1.1)`. I am not sure why and did not trouble-shoot further, since I only need this `VM` with `RStudio` to perform one function (send email by Outlook).